# let generic function match another function's specific overload signature

Tags: node.js, typescript, node-mongodb-native

Try to write a generic function to match the second overload signature of `findOne()` method of `Collection` class.

```
import { Document, Filter, FindCursor, FindOptions, MongoClient, WithId } from 'mongodb'; // tags: ^5.6.0

const uri = '<connection string uri>';
const client = new MongoClient(uri);

function findUsers<TSchema extends Document = Document>(
    find_pattern: Filter<TSchema>,
    options?: FindOptions,
): FindCursor<WithId<TSchema>> {
    return client.db('main').collection('accounts').find(find_pattern, options);
}
```

The overload signatures of `findOne()`:

```
export declare class Collection<TSchema extends Document = Document> {
    //...
    find(): FindCursor<WithId<TSchema>>;
    find(filter: Filter<TSchema>, options?: FindOptions): FindCursor<WithId<TSchema>>;
    find<T extends Document>(filter: Filter<TSchema>, options?: FindOptions): FindCursor<T>;
    //...
}
```

Try to match below overload signature.

```
find(filter: Filter<TSchema>, options?: FindOptions): FindCursor<WithId<TSchema>>;
```

TSC throws two errors, the first error throws at the `return` keyword.

```
Type 'FindCursor<WithId<Document>>' is not assignable to type 'FindCursor<WithId<TSchema>>'.
  Type 'WithId<Document>' is not assignable to type 'WithId<TSchema>'.
    Type 'WithId<Document>' is not assignable to type 'EnhancedOmit<TSchema, "_id">'.(2322)
```

The second error throws at the `.find(find_pattern, options)`.

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(filter: Filter<Document>, options?: FindOptions<Document> | undefined): FindCursor<WithId<Document>>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'Filter<TSchema>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Filter<Document>'.
      Type 'Filter<TSchema>' is not assignable to type 'RootFilterOperators<WithId<Document>>'.
        Types of property '$and' are incompatible.
          Type 'Filter<WithId<TSchema>>[] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Filter<WithId<Document>>[] | undefined'.
            Type 'Filter<WithId<TSchema>>[]' is not assignable to type 'Filter<WithId<Document>>[]'.
              Type 'Filter<WithId<TSchema>>' is not assignable to type 'Filter<WithId<Document>>'.
                Type 'Filter<WithId<TSchema>>' is not assignable to type 'RootFilterOperators<WithId<WithId<Document>>>'.
                  Types of property '$where' are incompatible.
                    Type 'string | ((this: WithId<WithId<TSchema>>) => boolean) | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | ((this: WithId<WithId<Document>>) => boolean) | undefined'.
                      Type '(this: WithId<WithId<TSchema>>) => boolean' is not assignable to type 'string | ((this: WithId<WithId<Document>>) => boolean) | undefined'.
                        Type '(this: WithId<WithId<TSchema>>) => boolean' is not assignable to type '(this: WithId<WithId<Document>>) => boolean'.
                          The 'this' types of each signature are incompatible.
                            Type 'WithId<WithId<Document>>' is not assignable to ty
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgEQgYwK4gKYDsYA0cAYsADYzZRGm4AmAwhlAM7Q3D0DyYMwEuFkQCyAgOYQGZYHkJwA6sBgALAJJ04AXzgAzKBBBwA5CHEQ6AIyMBuOAHo7cGAEMxLAFxwAegFYAdABsfgAMAFChaAIs8MzAcAC8xgA8kbi42Gh8AnDRUJxicLEAfDYRUfBo0rIJcOkA7nCiuBJSMvgAFLEAlNbhOhi4mfy4upx0AKosVCxJACoAymjK2CDOcNgAHpT0LCjoWNWJqJg4+EXtoQCQOmMA+mDOMJRQuJ6kFFRzi8urRQRXEF4wxYAH43mMeFlBP8uuD6ExWNAkooVOovksVs4ikVEFcoNgYMwRpU2jA-JZ2iZnJwjF0-JEyGQMlDKc40JEBjAWLS-Dd6O0+XR7o9nrgiICoSweqFNKEgA)

package versions:

```json
"typescript": "^5.1.6",
"mongodb": "^5.6.0"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `findOne` overloads, it doesn't accept `TSchema`, but the `Document`:

```
export declare class Collection<TSchema extends Document = Document> {
    //...
    find(): FindCursor<WithId<TSchema>>;
    find(filter: Filter<TSchema>, options?: FindOptions): FindCursor<WithId<TSchema>>;
    find<T extends Document>(filter: Filter<TSchema>, options?: FindOptions): FindCursor<T>;
    //...
}
```

The `TSchema` is accepted by the `Collection` class, thus you can fix it just by passing your schema to the `collection` method:

```
function findUsers<TSchema extends Document = Document>(
    find_pattern: Filter<TSchema>,
    options?: FindOptions,
): FindCursor<WithId<TSchema>> {
    return client.db('main').collection<TSchema>('accounts').find(find_pattern, options);
}
```

[Link to Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgEQgYwK4gKYDsYA0cAYsADYzZRGm4AmAwhlAM7Q3D0DyYMwEuFkQCyAgOYQGZYHkJwA6sBgALAJJ04AXzgAzKBBBwA5CHEQ6AIyMBuOAHo7cGAEMxLAFxwAegFYAdABsfgAMAFChaAIs8MzAcAC8xgA8kbi42Gh8AnDRUJxicLEAfDYRUfBo0rIJcOkA7nCiuBJSMvgAFLEAlNbhOhi4mfy4upx0AKosVCxJACoAymjK2CDOcNgAHpT0LCjoWNWJqJg4+EXtoQCQOmMA+mDOMJRQuJ6kFFRzi8urRQRXEF4wxYAH43mMeFlBP8uuD6ExWNAkooVOovksVs4ikVEFcoNgYMwRpU2jA-JZ2iZnJwjF0-JEyGQMlD0T8sZTnGhIgMYCxaX4bvR2oK6PdHs9cERAVCWD1QppQkA)